# How to apply written defaults to a Magic Mouse (com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse)?

Tags: macos, mouse, defaults

Running OSX 10.7.4
I wrote a script to swap Apple Magic Mouse secondary click.

The following simple bash script do modify the system preferences (can be seen in System Preferences GUI), but the mouse secondary click is not really swapped.

```
#!/bin/bash
mmode=$(defaults read  com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode)
echo --- $mmode ---
if [ $mmode = 'TwoButton' ]; then
defaults write  com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse "save.MouseButtonMode.v1" -int 2
defaults write  com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode -string "TwoButtonSwapped"
echo LEFT HAND MODE
else
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse "save.MouseButtonMode.v1" -int 1
defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse MouseButtonMode -string "TwoButton"
echo RIGHT HAND MODE
fi
```

It seems the OS needs some reload/refresh command for the change to take effect.
Can anyone figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: restarting?! of course not. System Preferences GUI works well. I just need a shortcut script launched to avoid 5 clicks every time I need to swap hands

Comment: Also, I know it can be done with Automator Watch-Me-Do. But I will need two different Automator scripts since Watch-Me-Do can't be branched

Comment: Does the setting stay swapped if you close and reopen Sys Pref?

Comment: if I reopen Sys Pref settings stay swapped but has not effect until I open and click on the currently selected mode.

Comment: Does this happen with other mice? What about if you restart the mouse?

Comment: Restart mouse?
You mean the driver?
http://superuser.com/questions/301222/how-to-reset-restart-an-internal-macbook-trackpad-driver-on-os-x

Comment: No, I meant turn it on and off... but that might actually do the trick.

Comment: Yes it works, but reconnection can only be done via Sys Pref, again with various clicks...no good!

Comment: @Tal have you tried to relaunch the Finder.app? "killall Finder"

Comment: @E1Suave. No I didn't. I gave up...The Magic mouse is not worth the trouble as it's a pain to use :-(

Comment: In OS X Mojave this is still a mystery to me. Each time I create a new user I have a script to set all my preferences, I don't want to go through the song and dance that OS X makes me do.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any way to apply the changes, but you could also use UI scripting to change the setting.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    try
        set visible to false
    end try
    tell application "System Preferences" to reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.mouse"
    tell radio group 1 of window 1
        if value of radio button 1 is 1 then
            click radio button 2
        else
            click radio button 1
        end if
    end tell
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: System Events got an error: Can’t get radio group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.

See http://images.apple.com/magicmouse/images/software.jpg

Comment: I only have 10.8 and no Magic Mouse. If someone gets the script to work with the Magic Mouse style preference pane or in older versions, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: unfortunately apple script record won't capture sys perf actions. Automator does, but it won't reveal how it is done. I couldn't find any apple script example similar to the magic mouse windows :-(